# if 'statement' : 'statement' if 'statement' else 'statement' How this double if and else work?

Tags: python, if-statement

I cant understand this double if and else statement

full code is below and where is cant understand is

---

```
if not imgs[i].startswith('.'):
                label[j]=0 if imgs[i].split('.')[0]=='cat' else 1
```

---

```
def LoadDirImgList(sampleNum,path): 
    data = np.empty((sampleNum,3,32,32),dtype="float32")
    label = np.empty((sampleNum,),dtype ="uint8")
    imgs = os.listdir(path)
    num = len(imgs)
    j=0
    for i in range(num):
        if not imgs[i].startswith('.'):
            label[j]=0 if imgs[i].split('.')[0]=='cat' else 1
            img = Image.open(path+imgs[i])
            arr = np.asarray (img, dtype ="float32")
            data [j,:,:,:] = [arr[:,:,0],arr[:,:, 1],arr[:,:, 2]] 
            j=j+1
    return data, label
```

Comment: It is a python ternary expression. 0 if condition met else 1

Comment: FWIW, another way to write that assignment is `label[j] = int(imgs[i].split('.')[0] != 'cat')`. I think my version is more readable, YMMV. :)

Comment: Hi SwarmRL. Could you mention if any of the answers was helpful (or all, or none)?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is easier to understand for you if you add parenthesis:

```
if not imgs[i].startswith('.'):
            label[j]= ( 0 if imgs[i].split('.')[0]=='cat' else 1 )
```

The part in between parenthesis evaluates to 0 if the condition is met and otherwise evaluates to 1.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain without code....

```
If the snow cones are red, white or green play the song at the bottom
        If they are not red, white or green play Happy Birthday Song 
Play the National Anthem
```

Answer (score -1):

```
label[j]=0 if imgs[i].split('.')[0]=='cat' else 1
```

equals:

```
if imgs[i].split('.')[0]=='cat':
    label[j]= 0
else:
    label[j]= 1
```

Answer (score -1):

If you know c you can relate this to the ternary operator as:

```
label[j] = strcmp(splitted_imgs[0], "cat") ? 0: 1;
```

or in python an equivalent code would be(as mentioned by kingguy):

```
if imgs[i].split('.')[0] == 'cat':
    label[j] = 0
else:
    label[j] = 1
```

but since you are using python, a pythonic is always appreciated(as you are using):

```
label[j] = 0 if imgs[i].split('.')[0] == 'cat' else 1
```

Answer (score -1):

It is called [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).
The statement equals:

```
if imgs[i].split('.')[0] == 'cat':
    label[j] = 0
else:
    label[j] = 1
```

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Python), it is said:

> The general form (in Python) is:

```
result = x if a > b else y
```

Comment: Nope, not the same.  In OP's example, if `label` does not exist before, it won't exist afterwards.

Comment: @JacobVlijm what do you mean by "label does not exist before"?

Comment: The question is about the top two lines. If label was not defined earlier, it stil does not exist afterwards, if not `imgs[i].startswith('.')`. e.g. `print(label)` will raise `NameError`.

Comment: @JacobVlijm If `if not imgs[i].startswith('.'):` is true, then `if imgs[i].split('.')[0] == 'cat':
    label[j] = 0
else:
    label[j] = 1`, isn't that?

Comment: Yes, but if not, label *does not exist afterwards* if not defined before.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Then what is `label = np.empty((sampleNum,),dtype ="uint8")`??

Comment: Hi pwd, the question is syntatically, not coincidentally how it is in *this* context, but even *if* label exists, the meaning is quite different. The code in his example *leave label as it is* `if not imgs[i].startswith('.')`, *whatever that is*. In your snippet, it becomes either `0` or `1`.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Okay, I finally got it, but I just ''translated" the statement and didn't care about the name error.